# Using sed on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, sed

I am trying to use sed to replace certain Norwegian characters from the Windows-1252 encoding with the UTF-8 equivalent. 
In order to avoid the "Illegal byte sequence" error, I tried this:
LANG=C LC_ALL=C
which got rid of the error message, but no replacement takes place.

My script goes like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
#include <stdio.h>
LANG=C LC_ALL=C sed -e 's/Ê/æ/g' -e 's/¯/ø/g' -e 's/Ù/ø/g' -e 's/Â/å/g'
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You haven't given it any input to operate on : `sed 'commands' file` for example. Also, shell is not C so lose the `#include <stdio.h>` and `LANG=C` isn't doing anything useful AFAIK. Edit your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output.

Comment: If you are replacing letters in a text-file you can use iconv instead. Like 'iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8'. See syntax in 'man iconv'.

Comment: I know I have to include an input file. I left it out for sake of convenience since the path was very long. I included LANG=C to avoid the error message.

Comment: iconv worked! Thanks a lot! (Tusen takk!)